# Avoiding passing undefined variables to mysqli_stmt_bind_param?

Tags: php, mysqli

Unfortunately, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` doesn't prompt an error when an undefined variable is passed to the function (even with all errors enabled). So you could actually write something like this without getting so much as a warning (it just treats the undefined variable as `NULL`):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

$db = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
$Stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($Stmt, 'SELECT id FROM table WHERE value = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($Stmt, 's', $UndefinedVariable); // <---------
mysqli_stmt_execute($Stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($Stmt, $ID);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($Stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($Stmt);

?>
```

Now, I'm positive I already reported this to the PHP developers about a year ago, but I was basically told that they can't/won't fix it. However, I'm unable to find the report now...

So I'm hoping to find a solution to just get PHP to yell at me when I (probably) just made a typo in the source, which occasionally does happen! Is there a native solution to this?

Comment: Odd that it doesn't raise an E_NOTICE. In any case, a good IDE will warn you that `$UndefinedVariable` is not used. A static analysis tool like PHPStan will do the same.

Comment: Ah ok found it -- it doesn't raise an E_NOTICE because the 3rd parameter to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` is passed by reference. If you switch to PDO, you can use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()` -- this will throw an E_NOTICE as expected.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have considered switching from mysqli purely for this little flaw. But I prefer procedural programming, and last I checked PDO only has an OOP interface. Do you have any tips for procedural programming? Maybe a library?

Comment: You could write a simple wrapper function like `alternate_mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` that just does an `isset()` check first, but I wouldn't waste run-time cycles on that since this is really a compile-time issue. I'd use PHPStan, it will find a ton of probable errors in your code that you didn't even know you had.

Comment: *"mysqli_stmt_bind_param doesn't prompt an error (even with all errors enabled) in PHP"* - That's because it isn't a function that uses `mysqli_error($db)`, only for the querying function.

Comment: If you want "PHP" to send you an error, use error reporting. PHP and MySQL are two different animals and need to be dealt with respectively.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am enabling both MySQL and PHP errors. See updated code.

Comment: what happens when you use this instead? `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No difference - those are (were) already set, too. Trust me, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` simply *won't* report undefined variables (for the reasons outlined by other commenters above).

Answer (score 0):

The only native solution that doesn't involve code is to look through your error log for undefined variable notices.

As for a native solution involving code, do some basic input validation, e.g. using `isset($variable)`. For example, you could do the following:

```
if(!isset($UndefinedVariable)) {
    throw new Exception('Expected variabled "$UndefinedVariable" to be defined.');
}
```

In general you should really be doing input validation, anyway. It takes more time and makes your code longer, but it also ensures that your code is safer and does what you expect it to.

Comment: I do have input validation in place. But that doesn't prevent things like typos directly in the source. Unfortunately...

Comment: If you're concerned about typos in your source code, it would be best for you to use a proper IDE and/or a linter, that way your undefined variables are detected by default. Some IDEs have static code analysis built in as a native feature as well. PHP's weak typing system is a feature, and your only way around it is to use data validation, appropriate tools like an IDE and a linter, and/or monitoring your error logs. There's no other way around it.

Comment: I came up with one possible solution actually (see answers), but it may not be the best way... what do you think?

Comment: On the topic of proper IDEs -- are any of them actually able to detect when variables are "defined" through `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` for example? (i.e. **result** variables from a query?). As opposed to just your typical `$Variable = 'Value';` declarations.

Comment: Regarding your solution, I'm actually not sure how it helps. Don't you run into virtually the same problem, albeit passing a potentially undefined variable to a wrapper function instead of the native one? Granted it can be useful because you can e.g. validate your parameters in one place rather than potentially several.

Comment: Regarding IDEs, the answer is unfortunately "probably not". Please review the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and note that in the function definition, each bound variable for the result is prefixed by an ampersand (`&`), which means that any variable--even a previously undefined one--is valid, i.e. you don't need to declare or initialize a variable before using it. This is a feature, not a bug. An IDE will only catch this if it's a "smart" IDE designed to analyze variables for similar names and catch "possible" errors.

Comment: If you have any further questions, they will likely exceed the scope of your question. That being said, we can move this discussion to a chat if you would like to discuss this in greater depth.

Comment: On my solution: since the wrapper function does *not* access variables by reference (contrary to the built-in function), it will at least produce an error message. That's the key difference.

Comment: Excellent point. In that case a wrapper function will work for the sake of displaying errors, but you won't have the benefit of having those referenced variables retaining the new values on return. You would need to explicitly return those values and then update them outside of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Using a wrapper seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution?

```
function db_stmt_bind_param($Stmt, $Types, ...$Params)
{
    return mysqli_stmt_bind_param($Stmt, $Types, ...$Params);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($Stmt, $Types, ...[$Param1, $Param2, $Param3])
```

Both requires using splat operator, however, which is a relatively recent implementation.